# How to add windows media player control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-media-player

I have follow this [Link](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/using-windows-media-player-com-in-wpf/) for adding windows media play control in my wpf form.
I have getting following error:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

it works fine with dot net framework 3.5 but Issue with dot net framework 4.6.

How to resolve it Thanks.

Comment: Google "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" and you will get a lot of information about things to check to try and solve the problem

Comment: It works fine with dot net framework 3.5 but getting error in updated framework

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to include that information directly in your question. Specifically what version is it failing with.

Comment: If your intention is to play video or audio files, you can use the WPF controls itself. Instead of using WindowsForms control.
[http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/)